# TableViewCell contents duplicate when cell is selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode6

I have a tableview that has is calling a separate `UITableViewCell`. I have code to layout the cell in the `UITableViewCell` and this displays properly in my tableview. For some reason though, if i select the cell, the content in the cell is redrawn over the top of the cell.

Does anyone know why this would be? I've attached the code to draw my cell below.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (tableView == productInformationTable){

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        ProductImagesTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[ProductImagesTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        else{
            cell = [[ProductImagesTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        return cell;
    }

    else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        ProductQuantityTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[ProductQuantityTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        else{
            cell = [[ProductQuantityTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        return cell;
    }

    else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        ProductButtonsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[ProductButtonsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        else{
            cell = [[ProductButtonsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        return cell;
    }



    else {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        else{
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        return cell;
    }
}

else {
    return nil;
}
```

}

The code for my cell is below -

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

    }




- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    }

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    customButton = [[SAExpandableButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width - 50, self.frame.size.height/2 - 15, 30, 30)];
    customButton.layer.borderColor = [Styles priceRed].CGColor;
    customButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.5;
    customButton.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
    customButton.expandDirection = SAExpandDirectionLeft;
    customButton.numberOfButtons = 8;
    customButton.selectedIndex = 0;

    quantityLabel = [UILabel new];
    quantityLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, self.frame.size.height/2 - 10, 100, 20);
    quantityLabel.text = @"Quantity";
    [self addSubview:quantityLabel];


    customButton.buttonTitles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8", nil];

    [self addSubview:customButton];



}



- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if(cell.selectionStyle == UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone){
    return nil;
}
return indexPath;
NSLog(@"willSelectRow called");

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"Table Pressed");

}
```

Comment: Umm... not without seeing your code.

Comment: Please provide your relevant code parts so we can investigate the problem.

Comment: Sorry i've added it now. I know it has to be because layoutSubviews is being called each time, but I don't understand why.

Comment: still not relevant, we need to see didselectrow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not create your cell's subviews in `layoutSubviews` as it can get called any number of times. Use `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` for initialization and just layout them in `layoutSubviews` (hence the name).

Also you must use different `CellIdentifier`s for all your different cell types!

**Edit:**

To prevent the selection of of a cell you should use `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and return `nil` to prevent the selection.